# Iterating over Rows and Columns to add counts in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, iteration

I am trying to iterate over columns AND rows in Pandas to cross-reference a list I have and count the cooccurrences.

My dataframe looks like:

```
+-------+-----+-----+----+----+-------+-------+------+
| Lemma | Dog | Cat | Sg | Pl |  Good |  Okay |  Bad |
+-------+-----+-----+----+----+-------+-------+------+
| Dog   |   0 |   0 |  0 |  0 |   0   |   0   |  0   |
| Cat   |   0 |   0 |  0 |  0 |   0   |   0   |  0   |
+-------+-----+-----+----+----+-------+-------+------+
```

I have a list like:

```
c=[[dog, Sg, Good], [cat, Pl, Okay], [dog, Pl, Bad]
```

I want to go through every item in `Lemma`, find it in `c` and then for that list item look for any of the column names. If those column names are seen, I was to add +1. I also want to add a count if the Lemma items occur in a 3 word window of each other.

I've tried something like the following (ignoring the word window issue):

```
for idx, row in df.iterrows():
    for columns in df:
        for i in c:
            if i[0]==row:
                if columns in c[1]:
                    df.ix['columns','row'] +=1
```

But I get the error: "ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()."

My ideal results look like:

```
+-------+-----+-----+----+----+-------+-------+------+
| Lemma | Dog | Cat | Sg | Pl |  Good |  Okay |  Bad |
+-------+-----+-----+----+----+-------+-------+------+
| Dog   |   1 |   1 |  1 |  1 |   1   |   0   |  1   |
| Cat   |   2 |   0 |  0 |  1 |   0   |   1   |  0   |
+-------+-----+-----+----+----+-------+-------+------+
```

Thanks!

Comment: i think your results have issue why column Dog and lemma Cat contains 2 ?

Comment: output looks weird. why `Cat`-`Cat` is `0`, but `Dog`-`Cat` is `1` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. The ideal result shown in the question is not accurate.  There should never be a `cat` in the `dog` column and vise versa.
2. I wouldn't iterate through the `DataFrame`, I'd unpack the `list` of `lists` into a `dict` then load the `dict` into a `DataFrame`, as shown below.

## Code:

```
import pandas as pd

c=[['dog', 'Sg', 'Good'], ['cat', 'Pl', 'Okay'], ['dog', 'Pl', 'Bad'],
   ['dog', 'Sg', 'Good'], ['cat', 'Pl', 'Okay'], ['dog', 'Pl', 'Okay'],
   ['dog', 'Sg', 'Good'], ['cat', 'Sg', 'Good'], ['dog', 'Pl', 'Bad'],
   ['dog', 'Sg', 'Good'],['cat', 'Pl', 'Okay'], ['dog', 'Pl', 'Bad']]

Lemma = {'dog': {'dog': 0, 'Sg': 0, 'Pl': 0, 'Good': 0, 'Okay': 0, 'Bad': 0},
         'cat': {'cat': 0, 'Sg': 0, 'Pl': 0, 'Good': 0, 'Okay': 0, 'Bad': 0}}
```

Note: Each value in a `list` from `c` is a `key` in `Lemma`.  Reference [python dictionaries](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries).  e.g. With `x = ['dog', 'Sg', 'Good']`, `Lemma[x[0]][x[2]]` is the same as `Lemma['dog']['Good']`.  The initial value of `Lemma['dog']['Good']` = 0, therefore `Lemma['dog']['Good']` = 0 + 1, then next time it would be 1 + 1, etc.

```
for x in c:
    Lemma[x[0]][x[0]] = Lemma[x[0]][x[0]] + 1
    Lemma[x[0]][x[1]] = Lemma[x[0]][x[1]] + 1
    Lemma[x[0]][x[2]] = Lemma[x[0]][x[2]] + 1

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(Lemma, orient='index')
```

## Output:

[image]

## Plot

```
df.plot(kind='bar', figsize=(6, 6))
```

[image]

## Create the `dict` programmatically:

### create `sets` of words for the `dict` `keys` from the `list` of `lists`:

```
outer_keys = set()
inner_keys = set()
for x in c:
    outer_keys.add(x[0])  # first word is outer key
    inner_keys |= set(x[1:])  # all other words
```

### create `dict` of `dicts`:

```
Lemma = {j: dict.fromkeys(inner_keys | {j}, 0) for j in outer_keys}
```

### final `dict`:

```
{'dog': {'Okay': 0, 'Pl': 0, 'Good': 0, 'Bad': 0, 'Sg': 0, 'dog': 0},
 'cat': {'Okay': 0, 'Pl': 0, 'Good': 0, 'Bad': 0, 'Sg': 0, 'cat': 0}}
```

Comment: I figured this was the reasoning so I'll ask another question: the real data set has 5000 words and 500 variables I'd need to do this for. Is it advisable to do something like:

for i in range(5000):
    Lemma[x[0]][x[i]] = Lemma[x[0]][x[i]] + 1

Comment: The approach is sound. As with any data science, the first step, and 80% of your time is spent getting the data into a usable format.  That dict was constructed manually, if would be better to create a `dict` programmatically.  `dicts` are not the only data structure of python, but they are probably that main one.

Answer (score 0):

You have several things that need to be changed.

1) Your list probably needs to have `Dog` instead of `dog`, `Cat` instead of `cat`

2) You probably want: `for column in df.columns` instead of `for columns in df`

3) You probably want: `if i[0] == row['Lemma']` instead of `if i[0]==row:` (this is where it was breaking

4) You probably want `if column in i` instead of `if columns in c[1]`

5) You probably want `df.ix[idx, column] += 1` instead of `df.ix['columns','row'] +=1`